# How to fetch a value from a cursor object?

Tags: python

Below is my code.Function Combiner() that gives incorrect values:

```
[(Decimal('3213.713766'),)] [(Decimal('7.041164'),)]
```

I want only values `3213.713766 7.041164`

```
def data_generation():
    con=mysql.connector.connect()
    cursor=con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CALL `Pulse`.`SP_GetAverageBillRate`();")
    data=cursor.fetchall()
    return data

def data_generation2():
    con=mysql.connector.connect()
    cursor=con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CALL `Pulse`.`SP_GetAverageGrossProfit`();")
    data2=cursor.fetchall()
    return data2


def combiner():

    AverageBilling = data_generation()
    AverageGrossProfit = data_generation2()
    return [AverageBilling, AverageGrossProfit]
```

How do I get the values from this returned object?

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough fix, `fetchone` instead of all, so you don't get a list of results. You will get a tuple with one element, which you will select with `[0]` and then just cast the result to `float`:

```
def data_generation():
    con=mysql.connector.connect("connection_string")
    cursor=con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CALL `Pulse`.`SP_GetAverageBillRate`();")
    data = float(cursor.fetchone()[0])
    return data

def data_generation2():
    con=mysql.connector.connect("connection_string")
    cursor=con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CALL `Pulse`.`SP_GetAverageGrossProfit`();")
    data2 = float(cursor.fetchone()[0])
    return data2

def combiner():
    AverageBilling = data_generation()
    AverageGrossProfit = data_generation2()
    return [AverageBilling, AverageGrossProfit]
```

Comment: i have changed to fetchone and error is coming float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: @zzstar edited my answer a bit, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

All python database connectors that follow the [DBAPI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) will return tuples for rows, even if you only selected one column (or called a function that returns a single value, like you did).

This means that you always get a tuple, possbly containing just one item, for each `fetchone()` call.

You can get that single value by retrieving the item at index 0 from the tuple:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
data = row[0]
data2 = float(data)
```

Or in one line:

```
data2 = float(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Comment: Thanks its working but now i m getting error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 2)

Comment: @zzstar you should implement these fixes and ask a new question, since that error doesn't occure in this piece of code.